# Comment traduiriez-vous « debilitating » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, vocabulaire

J'ai entendu plusieurs fois des gens parler d'une activité ***debilitating***. Après avoir fait quelques recherches, je n'arrive pas à trouver une traduction en français qui me semble correcte.

Mon dictionnaire me donne **débilitant**, ce qui ne me convient pas vraiment ; je n'ai jamais entendu ce mot, j'aimerais une traduction plus « grand public ».

Et j'aimerais savoir également dans quel contexte vous utiliseriez cet adjectif.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En addition des mots déjà proposés, j'aime bien **incapacitant** qui insiste sur la perte des capacités, qu'elle soient physiques ou mentales, et qui est donc assez général.

Comment: J'aime beaucoup cette traduction, simple et comprehensible, avec peu de perte d'information.

Comment: Il me semble que le terme *incapacitant* serait plus justement la traduction de *disabling*, et évoquerait plutot la perte d'une ou plusieurs facultés, non l'amoindrissement de celles-ci. Ce pourquoi je trouve *abrutissant* bien meilleur.

Answer (score 6):

Pour renchérir dans le sens de ienissei, dans le contexte d'une tâche ou activité "debilitating" au plan moral, je penche pour [abrutissant](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/abrutissant) en français.

Answer (score 3):

Le site [Linguee](http://www.linguee.fr) propose les différentes traductions utilisées pour un mot sur les sites web multilangues. Malheureusement, l'utilisation ne veut pas toujours dire l'exactitude :-)

[Pour debilitating](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=anglais&query=debilitating), on voit que la traduction la plus utilisée est *débilitant*, presque toujours dans un contexte médical.

Mais il y a aussi potentiellement, contraignant, blessure, invalidant, exténuant, affaibli, épuisant, ou démanteler. À voir.

Comment: +1 pour invalidant

Answer (score 2):

"Débilitant" est un mot français (mais sans doute encore plus inusité qu'en anglais), mais on pourrait suggérer: affaiblissant, alanguissant, amollissant, invalidant, usant; ou encore: décourageant, démoralisant, démotivant, déprimant, désespérant. La première liste si c'est plutôt au sens physique; la seconde pour le sens moral.

Comment: C'est surtout que *debilitating* est de l'anglais relativement courant, alors que *débilitant* est strictement médical (et donc a un champ plus restreint).